# Providing service alias in Angular 7 breaks build execution

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-aot, angular-builder

I have written a service `MyService` and a mocked version of it – `MyServiceMock`, for unit tests providing and using the mocked service's result until my BE is ready.

I used `MyService` as alias of `MyServiceMock`, so I will not have to change my code in the future when the BE is ready:

In my services module I use:

```
import { MyServiceMock as MyService } from './my-service/my-service-mock.service';

const providers: Array<Provider> = [
  MyService,

...
```

And the same in my components:

```
import { MyServiceMock as MyService } from './my-service/my-service-mock.service';

...

 constructor(
   myServce: myService,

...
```

And it worked fine with `ng serve` and `ng build`... until I served the build. There was a runtime error in the browser `MyService is undefined`. But note that when served through Angular `ng serve` all worked fine. And there were no warnings and errors in the `ng build` | `ng build --prod` build processes.

The solution below is simple but I would appreciate any explanations of that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of faking an import you can simply tell Angular to provide your fake service when the real one is requested. A [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lp634h?file=src/app/app.module.ts) as an example.

in `app.module.ts` in the `providers`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RealService,
      useClass: FakeService
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now every time the RealService is requested the fake service will be served instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

In the services module we provide the mocked service as-is, without alias. And we use alias only in the components:

```
import { MyServiceMock } from './my-service/my-service-mock.service';

const providers: Array<Provider> = [
  MyServiceMock,

...
```